# unwanted constraint personal hotspot start bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

After I start my app in the device,
if the personal hotspot is showing,
xcode write in the console :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146dd7cf0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x146dd43e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x146dd2ee0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146dbd950 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x146dd43e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x146dd2ee0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146dd7cf0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x146dd43e0]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x146dd2ee0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

my app **does not** use auto-layout or constraints. (ios 9.3.5, ios 11)

the problem is also that the rootViewController in normal state is 0,0 origin,
but when there is call It's 0,20 and I can't change it to 0,0.

EDIT:
I managed to fix this by adding

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
}
```

**BUT** Is there way to remove the hotspot/incall constraints ?

I want the view.frame.origin will be 0,0 also when hotspot/incall is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try listening to this method (`willChangeStatusBarFrame`) of `UIApplicationDelegate` for change in status bar's frame and modify your view position accordingly:

During a phone-call, the new, changed status bar frame in an **iPhone SE** is as follows:

```
CGRect  (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 40))
```

This is when status bar is in normal state:

```
CGRect  (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 20))
```

---

**So when the device is in call, you can just offset your view's `y` value `+20` points or set to `0` as you originally wanted and FIXED.** This is the right/clean way to alter your frame in response to status bar frame change. It is better than setting view's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

---

However, you can try breaking the constraints as you need using the following code in your `willChangeStatusBarFrame`, but it is **NOT RECOMMENDED**, since we're breaking constraints which was set by `UIKit` and that might cause problems. We're basically breaking the constraints of `UITextEffectsWindow` by iterating through the app's array of windows:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
    for(UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if([window.class.description containsString:@"UITextEffectsWindow"]) {
            [window removeConstraints:window.constraints];
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
        if window.self.description.contains("UITextEffectsWindow") {
                window.removeConstraints(window.constraints)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this I already solved with "fix". I want the "clean" way.
Meaning, try to get rid of the unwanted constraint (my app don't use auto-layout) and maybe this will make the uiview always 0,0

Comment: you know how to get rid of the constraint ? I tried few things without success.
I don't see any reason why the uiview by defualt need to change his origin beacuse there is in-call, cause when there is no call, the status bar is 20 and uiview is 0,0

Comment: May be because it is how the view is constrained to be lowered when there is in-call. The breaking of constraints (as in your warning message) seems to be a bug at Apple's. Pls check edited answer.

Comment: I'll check this later and update.
but, you cover everthing.
thanks.